# AddForce works strangely

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game: side view basketball in Unity3D. I want the script to calculate the force of impact on the ball at which the ball will reach the basket based on the value of the distance from the ball to the basket. But I don’t know how to write it correctly, so I edit the impact force manually. There is also the problem that when the ball hits, in the first two frames the ball travels a much greater distance than in the rest. The Shoot method is called in Update if the ball is in the bot's collision zone. Ball hit code and screenshots (Sequence of screenshots: 1-frame before hit, 2-first frame after hit, 3-second frame after hit, 4-3rd frame after hit):

```
private void Shoot{ 
var heading = pointTarget.position - go_ball.transform.position;
var distance = heading.normalized;
var distancemag = heading.magnitude;
go_ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(distance * distancemag * UpForce * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
go_ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(distance * distancemag * LeftForce * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.VelocityChange);}
```

I also adjust MaxVelocity in a separate ball script method(idk maybe problem hides here)

```
if (rb_ball.velocity.magnitude > MaxVelocity)
{
rb_ball.velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(rb_ball.velocity, MaxVelocity);
}
```

[image: 1 frame]

[image: 2 frame]

[image: 3 frame]

[image: 4 frame]

As you can see the difference in the distance from the ball in the first two frames is different. What could be the problem?

Comment: I think the issue is with the separate ball script

Comment: what are the result if you remove the separate ball script? (just comment it out)

Comment: I think you are using `Vector3.ClampMagnitude` incorrectly, [read this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ClampMagnitude.html)

Comment: the ball will fly into the unknown, too much force is applied, but if you make the force less then the ball will not reach the basket

Comment: try doing this `var distancemag = heading.magnitude * 0.2;` and let me know

Comment: do the above, while the other script is commented out

Comment: unity gave an error "Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector3' and 'double'"

Comment: sorry, i forgot it was a vector3, try `var distancemag = Vector3.Scale(heading.magnitude, 0.2);`

Comment: else do `var distancemag = Vector3.Scale(heading.magnitude, new Vector3(0.2, 0.2, 0.2));`

Comment: in the first case gives an error "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3', Argument 2: cannot convert from 'double' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3' "
in the second case, it gives an error "Argument 1, 2, 3: cannot convert from 'double' to 'float'"

Comment: long story short, you need to lower the value of distancemag by maybe 50%, good luck lol